Can't select element with JS on Microsoft Copilot
I want to select element on Microsoft's Copilot webpage, but it always returns undefined.
So, I am trying to select that element as ussually with:
document.getElementById('searchbox')

Can anybody explain me how it works? And how can I get this element selected?

Try document.querySelector('#searchbox'). Additionally, make sure your script runs after the element is loaded, either by placing it at the end of the HTML body or using an event listener like DOMContentLoaded.

No, it doesn't work.

What is shadow root

It is hidden in shadowRoot API.
You have to navigate through DOM to retrieve it:
const root1 = document.getElementsByClassName('cib-serp-main')[0].shadowRoot;
const root2 = root1.getElementById('cib-action-bar-main').shadowRoot;
const root3 = root2.children[2].getElementsByTagName('cib-text-input')[0].shadowRoot;
const searchbox = root3.getElementById('searchbox');

